# I am trying to disable Backspace inside the input field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In this example I want to disable the backspace key on the input field.

I am passing the $event in my template as:

```
<input (input)="onInput($event)">
```

while in my app.component.ts file the function is like this:

```
onInput(e:KeyboardEvent){
if(e.keycode===8){
e.preventDefault();
}else{
console.log(e.which);
}
```

Also Typescript is complaining about e.keycode and e.which as being deprecated.

Edit: I forgot to add double quotes in the question on : (input)="onInput()"

Comment: Did you try e.key?

Comment: yes i tried e.key. it didn't work for me

Comment: you may check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869026/prevent-backspace-in-input-text-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the output of input element
from `(input)` to `(keydown)`

Comment: It works. but what is the difference ? does it not work with (input) ?

Comment: (input) output emit the input field details not the keyboard related details but you need keycode that is available in keyBoardevent which is emitted by (keydown) output or (keyup)

Comment: Oh........ Okay . Thanks for the Answer. it makes sense now.

Comment: What about the Issue of deprecation though. is there a way around that ? especially with event.which .